# Change the background color of a series of text highlighted by mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of paragraphs and I want to change the background color of some text selected.
For example:

```
<p>The quick brown</p>
<p>fox jumps over</p>
<p>the lazy dog</p>
```

The user selected the text range from "brown" to "lazy" and clicked on change color button. What I want to do is to do modifications on the selected text such as change color, size etc.

Comment: With "select" you mean mark it with the cursor?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: Why do you need this? It's going to be rather complicated with getting the selection, inserting spans across several paragraphs etc.

Comment: Take a look to this SO-Question and then change the background with jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Comment: @dTDesign getting the selected text is the easy part.

Comment: @adeneo yes i know it's complicated, i would like to get an answer that would at least let me retrieve the nodes under my selection

Comment: @adeneo: so what is the hard part?

Comment: Maybe will you find some ideas here (http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html) or here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)

Comment: @dTDesign, Ricola3d, why don't you put those as your answers

Comment: @dTDesign you must insert a span between the selected text so that you can change the selected text background color. In this case the OP uses more then just one `<p>` so it's going to be very complicated to do this. Imagine if the user selects the _The quick brown fox_, how would you put a `span` in there between two `<p>`-s? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fSnTX/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is as far as i got (only works for text in the same block element)
if anyone can improve on this please do.

replace 'buttonid' with the id for your button

```
function selectHTML() {

try {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var c = document.selection.createRange();
        return c.htmlText;
    }

    var nNd = document.createElement("span");
    var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    w.surroundContents(nNd);
    return nNd.innerHTML;
} catch (e) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    } else {
        return getSelection();
    }
}

}


$(function() {

$('#button_id').click( function() {
    var mytext = selectHTML();
    $('span').css({"color":"blue"});
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

I hope by the help of this post you will be able to achive what you really want.

Comment: This is not the same...

Comment: @Balint Bako, Iknow, but the link was to give an idea that how to get the selected text, based on that he can add logic to changes text's background color.